# sqlalchemy transaction does not rollback

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, zope

For my integration test, I custom wrote the base class from `unittest.TestCase`.

```
def initialize_sql(engine, dbsession):
    dbsession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)  # ensure the database is clean!
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    try:
        populate(dbsession)
    except IntegrityError:
        transaction.abort()

class HeavyTestBaseCase(unittest.TestCase):
    __TEST__ = False
    test_ini = 'test.ini'

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        TEST_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        settings = appconfig('config:' + os.path.join(TEST_ROOT, cls.test_ini))
        cls.engine = engine_from_config(settings, prefix='sqlalchemy.')
        print 'Creating the tables on the test database %s' % cls.engine

        cls.dbsession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(
                extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
        config = Configurator(settings=settings)
        initialize_sql(cls.engine, cls.dbsession)

    def tearDown(self):
        transaction.abort() # strange name for rollback ...

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        Base.metadata.drop_all(cls.engine)
```

Now here is the test case:

```
from mock import Mock, patch
from aurum.models import User
from aurum.user import register_user

class TestRegisterUserIntegration(HeavyTestBaseCase):
    __TEST__ = True

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.uid = 'uid1234'
        cls.username = 'user01'
        cls.password = 'password01'
        cls.masteru = 'masteru'
        cls.masterp = 'masterp'

        cls.gcs_patcher = patch('aurum.user.GCS', autospec=True)
        cls.gcs = cls.gcs_patcher.start()
        cls.gcs.return_value.register.return_value = cls.uid
        super(TestRegisterUserIntegration, cls).setUpClass()

    def test_register_user01_successful_return_useid_and_shared_key(self):
        result = register_user(self.username, self.password, self.masteru, self.masterp)
        self.assertEqual(result.keys(), ['user_id', 'shared_key'])
        self.assertEqual(result['user_id'], self.uid)

    def test_register_user01_successful_write_to_database_query_is_not_none(self):
        register_user(self.username, self.password, self.masteru, self.masterp)
        result = self.dbsession.query(User).filter_by(username=self.username).first()
        self.assertTrue(result is not None)
```

But rollback didn't do anything. One of the tests will fail because of duplicating keys constraint, which means the commit didn't get drop.

In the actual code, before returning I wrote `transaction.commit()` to commit the changes.

Any idea what's going on? Thanks

---

Adapt @zzzek's advise, here's the traceback:
http://pastebin.com/K9fin7ZH

The actual code is about this:

```
def add_user(dbsession, username, password):
    with transaction.manager:
        user = User(...)
        dbsession.add(user)
```

Comment: any chance you could simplify and just say "cls.dbsession = Session(bind=engine)" ?  scoped_session, sessionmaker() and zope.transaction could be skipped entirely for your tests.   your tearDown() would just be "cls.dbsession.rollback()".

Comment: @zzzeek thanks! lovely how the creator of sqlalchemy is giving it a try! It didn't work. I tried `Session` method before. See edit above. I will try to come up with a small testable example later today. Currently, I have to give unique values for each test. Not a big burden, but would be really nice to rollback :p

Comment: the form I use is that listed here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction .  This approach will ensure that even if your test ends up calling Session.commit(), the "outer" transaction is rolled back.

Comment: @zzzeek I will give this a try! Thanks for pointing me to the doc, I missed this one.

Comment: @CppLearner, did you ever get this working? I've been struggling for two weeks with Pyramid + SQLAlchemy and rolling back transactions in unit tests, and I've tried everything I can find via Googling (sontek's blog, the Pyramid testing docs, the SQLAlchemy docs, many suggestions from the Pyramid framework authors, my own recipes). Nothing I've tried has worked. Curious if you ever come up with a solution.

Comment: @JimStewart I think I managed to get away with this problem by rewriting the test. I have to dig this in a few days. I am about to finish my internship soon but this week is a little busy than usual. promise will get back at this this weekend.